# jQuery Ajax function getJSON() is not getting called

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#property').keyup(function() {
          var query = $(this).val();
      $('#results').html(query);
              $.getJSON('InstantSearchServlet?property=' + query, null, callBackProperty);
              }
      });    
});
```

For some reason the InstantSearchServlet is never getting called but when I directly call the servlet by editing the url to /InstantSearchServlet?property=e for example I get the desired result. I have tried putting a / before InstantSearchServlet... and that doesn't change anything.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at the request in Firbug/Chrome dev tools? It's usually easy to spot the difference there between your manually entered request (look at that one too) and the one generated by your suspect code.

Comment: If you're using Firefox, get Live HTTP Headers -extension. It enables you to capture all header information on http requests - this might show you the error.

Comment: What happens when you change your call to `$.getJSON('InstantSearchServlet?property=' + query, callBackProperty);`?  You don't have to pass anything for the data parameter if it's `null`.  Not sure if that would work, but it may be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of .val(), try .html() or .text()